# How to detect when a user joins a voice channel?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am currently trying to make a bot for my server and one of the things I want to do is have it detect whenever a user joins any voice channel and simply make it send a message. I can't personally figure it out or find any answers on the internet as most of the time people are detecting it based on a command while I want it to be passive. I know that voiceStateUpdate has been changed and some things are different from how I've seen others use it in the past.

If anyone has any solutions please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In discord.js v.12 the listener you need to use is indeed [`voiceStateUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate). It has the parameters [`oldState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) and [`newState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState). With those you can detect a number of things including the `member` object.

Using that you might use something like this to detect if a user or bot is connecting or disconnecting a voice channel.

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    // check for bot
    if (oldState.member.user.bot) return;

    // the rest of your code
})
```

Comment: it's always a good idea to look at the documentation first :)

Comment: This doesn't say how to tell whether they disconnected or connected, just one of the two. The documentation does not say, because it's generally terrible.

Comment: @stackers see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64866099/how-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-voice-channel-in-discord-with-discord-js-v12/64866464#64866464) helps you out

Answer (score 7):

```js
    client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
        if (newState.channelID === null) console.log('user left channel', oldState.channelID);
        else if (oldState.channelID === null) console.log('user joined channel', newState.channelID);
        else console.log('user moved channels', oldState.channelID, newState.channelID);
    });
```

Comment: I get `user moved channels undefined undefined` in the console for all three cases (left, joined, moved) when using this code.

Comment: `newState.channel.id` worked better for me than `newState.channelId`

Comment: discordjs likes to make arbitrary changes between versions so it's always best to reference the docs